Label not updating when reading from text file
I have this Private Sub that reads a text file line by line and outputs to a textbox, I want to display the amount of lines read as it goes but when I run the lbl_LinesRead.Text only gets updated once the file read completes.
What am I doing wrong?
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_StartProcess.Click

    Dim linesRead As Integer
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim stringReader As String
    linesRead = 0
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(fileToRead)

    Do

        stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
        TXT_Output.AppendText(stringReader & vbCrLf)
        linesRead += 1
        lbl_LinesRead.Text = linesRead.ToString


     Loop Until stringReader Is Nothing

End Sub

Number to update on each line read

Is this a WinForms Project? -- Since you have a closed loop that takes over the UI Thread, you have to let lbl_LinesRead refresh its content. If it's WinForms, add lbl_LinesRead.Update() after you have set the text, see how it goes

You need to force the label to redraw. You can do easily by adding
lbl_LinesRead.Refresh()

after lbl_LinesRead.Text = linesRead.ToString
Here is a .gif of the result (slowed down):


The UI runs on a single thread, and you have options for doing work, such as reading individual lines from a file, on different threads. When a UI event is handled such as in your example, it runs on the UI thread. The majority of what you are doing is processing a file so that code doesn't belong in the button click handler.
You are overloading the UI thread with this loop and you will notice in addition to your lbl_LinesRead not updating until the end, you form will be frozen as the thread is jammed up with work.
For offloading work, one option is Async / Await.
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_StartProcess.Click
    Await Task.Run(AddressOf ReadFile)
End Sub

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Using fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(fileToRead)
        Dim stringReader As String
        Dim linesRead = 0
        Do
            stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
            linesRead += 1
            Me.Invoke(
                Sub()
                    TXT_Output.AppendText(stringReader & vbCrLf)
                    lbl_LinesRead.Text = linesRead.ToString
                End Sub)
        Loop Until stringReader Is Nothing
    End Using
End Sub

The Task.Run runs the code passed to it on the thread pool - off the UI. Since it's off the UI, any UI updates must now be invoked back to the UI thread.
Also, any disposable object should be disposed of when you're done with it. That's the purpose of the Using
1024 lines read:

